# Uvmapping and UVpeeling - How did they get the textures in the first place?? (eg. Coke can)

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

Really enjoying my progress in Blender so far. Have got to the stage where I know many things so i can at least make some simple projects nad fix the simplest of problems by myself now so its starting to become fun.

It's got me wondering something though, and Googling this particular question was quite difficult as it just brought up info about mapping the texture back onto a cylinder or can model etc.

So what would be the terminology used for the unwrap process of a real life texture, such as if I wanted to take a energy drink i have at home and turn it into a flat texture?
I'm unsure of exactly what that process is called, and the best way to go about it (bearing in mind, all i really have is a half-decent mobile phone camera to play with and not much other hardware)

PS. Its only for a fun personal project so I am not bothered about copyrights and not worried too much about superior AAA-level quality just yet etc , just wondering how to do this thats all.

One way I can think is just take lots of photos and splice them together, but this seems way too much relying on me (the human) to get things accurate. I'm sure you guys knw a better way :)

Thanks for any help guys

Comment: This question isn't exactly about Blender, but you could either Google an image of the flat label, or you could "unwrap" the actual can (or bottle label) by cutting a straight line down the seam and lay it flat on a scanner bed.  It would be very difficult to stitch photos of a convex object together.

Comment: I don't think the process of taking a real-world object's picture(s) and turning it/them to a texture even has a name... I hear a lot of people simply calling it "Phototexturing" though, and some call it "Photounwrapping".

Comment: ah thanks for the replies. Like i see there are many Coke versions so im thinking there must be some kind of way of doing it with taking multiple pictures of the can, but im only guessing. I wanted to do it with an energy drink and there arent any pre-made versions online. Perhaps if I manage it i will post it :) I was thinking about unwrapping the can but think ill still need to take a few pics of it to get it to look flat in the texture. Cheers for letting me know im not missing something obvious at least that does it for me.